# NSLineBreakByWordWrapping not working if word is too long

Tags: ios, nsstring

Hi i am trying to resize string according to the text inside. But if the text (1 word text like link) is too long for the width that i used to resize it like below; label not fits it's size. The code that i am using is;

```
UILabel *gettingSizeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
gettingSizeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
gettingSizeLabel.text = messageData.TEXT;
gettingSizeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
gettingSizeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(240, 9999);
CGSize expectSize = [gettingSizeLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
```

As I write i want to resize text width to 240 (max), also it needs to be multiple lines. But the result can be calculated more than 240. 
Thanks

Comment: Also, this line is illegal: `gettingSizeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;` - `lineBreakMode` is not a bitmask. You pick _one_ line break mode. I'm surprised this would even compile, but the fact that it does is a good reason to switch to Swift, where this mistake is impossible to make. - Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is illegal:

```
gettingSizeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

`lineBreakMode` is not a bitmask. I'm surprised this would even compile, but the fact that it does is a good reason to switch to Swift, where this mistake is impossible to make.

If you fix that, it works fine (this is Swift, but it won't give you any trouble):

```
let s = "https://test.mobiletest.com/apps/12345678/install/abc123abc123abc123abc124"
let lab = UILabel()
lab.numberOfLines = 0
lab.text = s
lab.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
let result = lab.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(240,10000))
// (232.666666666667, 61.0)
```

Comment: Ok i got the break inside the word issue. But is is still not working if i set the lineBreakInfo to `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` (also with setting the parameter `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`)?

Comment: I using this code inside `UITableView` 's `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method to calculate the height for row without `autolayout` feature.The `messageData.TEXT` is a link something like https://test.mobiletest.com/apps/12345678/install/abc123abc123abc123abc124.

Comment: Finally i found the problem; The label that i calculated size is a standard `UILabel` class. But the label i use inside the `UITableView` is a custom label with insets. So i guess the size problem is because of that. Thanks @matt, your code is totally working.